# When im creating a new Project in android using Android 4.4 system image then R.java not Generating

Tags: android

whenever im creating a new project in android using android 4.4 then it's not generating R.java i tired to solve this problem. Even i tried Cleaning, Building, and Selecting Buildpath.

Please give me solution

Comment: does it generates R.java using another version of android?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it does not generate because you didn't downloaded the SDK completely.

Open CMD and type "android sdk". You'll have to download the samples, the Google API and the sources related to your version of SDK.

Answer (score 0):

you must have problem with your res folder, just check you included the library AppCompact its required library for new ide projects.

[site1](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)